# how do you parse out a text value in php

Tags: php

I have a line like this:

```
   $line1= "System configuration: lcpu=96 mem=393216MB ent=16.00"
```

I need to parse out lcpu, mem and ent values from this string. I have tried something like this:

```
  $lcpu=preg_match('/(?P<lcpu>\w+)= (?P<digit>\d+)/', $line1, $matches);
```

does not seem to be getting the lcpu values from the string $line1, any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What values *does* it get?  How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Also, you have a space after your `=` in the regex.  In your string, there is no space.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, after correcting, I get this value, lcpu=96. I need the number, 96 only.

Comment: How are you getting the value?  Check your `$matches` array, `96` should be in there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've nearly got a query string there, so maybe

```
$string = explode(": ", $line1);
$string = str_replace(" ", "&", $string[1]);
parse_str($string, $values);

echo $values['lcpu'];
```

Comment: thank you for this. if the lcpu has a text rather than number, how would I only include numbers (digits)?

Answer (score 2):

One other way to pares strings:

```
$line1= "System configuration: lcpu=96 mem=393216MB ent=16.00";

list($lcpu, $mem, $ent) = sscanf($line1, "System configuration: lcpu=%d mem=%dMB ent=%f");
```

Comment: Downside here is that the order of key/value pairs is very important :/. Otherwise, this feels the most elegant of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to parse a string. Explode is usually faster than using a regex, so this way may be more performant than the methods which rely on regular expressions.

```
list( , , $lcpu_pair )= explode( " ", $line1 );

list( , $lcpu_value ) = explode( "=", $lcpu_pair );
```

`$lcpu_value` will contain '96'.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple function to get the string between two strings. If the lcpu value is always going to be prefixed by "lcpu=" and end with a " " (space) then you could use:

```
    function getBetween($str, $start, $end)
    {
        $r = explode($start, $str);
        if (isset($r[1])) 
        {
            $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
            return $r[0];
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and just say:

```
   if (getBetween($line1, 'lcpu=', ' ')) { ... }
```

It'll return false if nothing is found.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would parse by syntax instead (rather than searching for specific keys):

```
<?php

$input = "System configuration: lcpu=96 mem=393216MB ent=16.00";

// Strip out "System configuration: "
$values = preg_replace('~^.*?:\s*$~', '', $input);

// Split on whitespace separator
$values = preg_split('~\s+~', $values);

// Convert to associative array
foreach ($values as $i => $item)
{
    // Explode on assignment (=)
    list($k, $v) = explode('=', $item);
    $values[$k] = $v;
    unset($values[$i]);
}
```